# How to promisify?

Tags: javascript, promise, bluebird

I have this sort of function:

```
someFunction.someMethod('param1', function(err, res1, res2) {
  req.method(res1, function(err) {
    if (!err) {
      console.log('Yes!');
    }
  });
})(req, res); // <-- This one's the problem!
```

Now when I try to promisify it:

```
var a = Promise.promisify(someFunction.someMethod);

a('param1').spread(function(res1, res2) {
  console.log('Yes!');
}).catch(function(err) {

});
```

it doesn't work anymore, because I cannot put the `(req, res)` at the end of it. How to achieve this?

Comment: I have an article that examples the use quite clearly. Check it out http://grizzlybit.info/2017/09/29/Node-JS-8-Util-Promisify/

Answer (score 2):

I would try this:

```
var a = Promise.promisify(function(arg, cb) {
    someFunction.someMethod(arg, cb)(req, res);
});

a('param1').spread(function(res1, res2) {
  console.log('Yes!');
}).catch(function(err) {

});
```

…and yes, it's ugly. This partial application might however be a sign that the function returned by `someFunction.someMethod('param1', …)` is supposed to be called multiple times; and your callback would be called as many times - where you cannot use promises any more.