# Using Promise.all() for multiple http/oauth queries

Tags: javascript, oauth, promise

I'm trying to wait for the output of two OAuth calls to an API, and I'm having trouble retrieving the data from those calls.  If I use Promise.all(call1,call2).then() I am getting information about the request object.

First, here's the setup for the fitbit_oauth object:

```
var fitbit_oauth = new OAuth.OAuth(
    'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/request_token',
    'https://api.fitbit.com/oauth/access_token',
    config.fitbitClientKey,
    config.fitbitClientSecret,
    '1.0',
    null,
    'HMAC-SHA1'
);

foodpath = 'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/foods/log/date/' + moment().utc().add('ms', user.timezoneOffset).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.json';
activitypath = 'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/' + moment().utc().add('ms', user.timezoneOffset).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.json';

Promise.all([fitbit_oauth.get(foodpath, user.accessToken, user.accessSecret), 
             fitbit_oauth.get(activitypath, user.accessToken,   
                                            user.accessSecret)])
                .then(function(arrayOfResults) {
                    console.log(arrayOfResults);
                }
```

I want arrayOfResults to give me the data from the calls, not information about the requests.  What am I doing wrong here?  I'm new to promises so I'm sure this is easy for someone who isn't.

The callback for a single fitbit_oauth call is as follows:

```
fitbit_oauth.get(
                'https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities/date/' + moment().utc().add('ms', user.timezoneOffset).format('YYYY-MM-DD') + '.json',
                user.accessToken,
                user.accessSecret,
                function (err, data, res) {
                    if (err) {
                        console.error("Error fetching activity data. ", err);
                        callback(err);
                        return;
                    }

                data = JSON.parse(data);
                console.log("Fitbit Get Activities", data);

                // Update (and return) the user
                User.findOneAndUpdate(
                    {
                        encodedId: user.encodedId
                    },
                    {
                        stepsToday: data.summary.steps,
                        stepsGoal: data.goals.steps
                    },
                    null,
                    function(err, user) {
                        if (err) {
                            console.error("Error updating user activity.", err);
                        }
                        callback(err, user);
                    }
                );
            }
        );
```

Thanks to jfriend00 I got this working, here's the new code:

```
function fitbit_oauth_getP(path, accessToken, accessSecret) {
    return new Promise (function(resolve, reject) {
        fitbit_oauth.get(path, accessToken, accessSecret, function(err, data, res) {
            if (err) {
                 reject(err);
            } else {
                 resolve(data);
            }
        }
     )
})};

Promise.all([fitbit_oauth_getP(foodpath, user.accessToken, user.accessSecret), 
    fitbit_oauth_getP(activitypath, user.accessToken, user.accessSecret)])
        .then(function(arrayOfResults) {
            console.log(arrayOfResults);
    });
```

Comment: What does `fitbit_oauth.get()` return?

Comment: I added more information showing how it works with a callback, hopefully this will help clarify my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Promise.all()` only works properly with asynchronous functions when those functions return a promise and when the result of that async operation becomes the resolved (or rejected) value of the promise.

There is no magic in `Promise.all()` that could somehow know when the fitbit functions are done if they don't return a promise.

You can still use `Promise.all()`, but you need to "promisify" the fitbit functions which is a small wrapper around them that turns their normal callback approach into returning a promise that was then resolved or rejected based on the callback result.

Some references on creating a promisified wrapper:

[Wrapping Callback Funtions](http://promise-nuggets.github.io/articles/07-wrapping-callback-functions.html)

[How to promisify?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26254104/how-to-promisify)

---

If you have an async function that accepts a callback to provide the async result such as `fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, callback)`, then you can "promisify" it like this:

```
function renameP(oldPath, newPath) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        fs.rename(oldPath, newPath, function(err) {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve();
            }
        });
    });
};


renameP("orig.txt", "backup.txt").then(function() {
   // successful here
}, function(err) {
    // error here
});
```

---

Some promise libraries such as [Bluebird](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md) have a built in `.promisify()` method that will do this for you (it will return a function stub that can be called on any function that follows the node.js async calling convention).

Comment: Then once I do this I can use Promise.all([renameP, foobar]) ?

Comment: Got it, changed the information in my original question to include the answer.  Thanks!